# How do I swap column values in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Employee

```
 Eno     ename     AttributeValue      AttributeName  
 1       aa           a123             abc
 2       bbb          b123             dcf
 3       cc           c7sd             wew3
```

I want to swap the data from column `AttributeValue` to `AttributeName` and `AttributeName` to `AttributeValue`

For Example:

```
Eno     ename     AttributeValue   AttributeName  
1       aa        abc              a123
2       bbb       dcf              b123
3       cc        wew3             c7sd
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
UPDATE employee
SET AttributeValue = AttributeName, 
    AttributeName = AttributeValue
```

However, unless both columns have the exact same definition, you risk losing information.

Comment: "unless both columns have the exact same definition, you risk loosing information." - just to be sure, are you saying unless the two columns are same datatype we could loose info? Or what do you mean by definition? thx

Comment: @VoodooChild - data type, yes. Though that includes precision and size if relevant.

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple. Coming from a C++ mindset my brain kept saying "nah... that won't work. Both value's will end up being whatever the initial value of `AttributeName` was."

Comment: @druciferre It's declarative programming. Say what you want, not how to accomplish it.

Comment: The C++ approach was killing me, this is brilliant! So easy Wow !

Comment: I looked it up and it's actually correct according to the SQL standard. The following is taken from the session about 'update statement: searched' of SQL-1992: 'the value expressions are effectively evaluated for each row of T before updating any row of T'.

Answer (score 14):

```
Update employee
Set attributeValue = attributeName,
    attributeName = attributeValue
```

Answer (score 7):

`update Employee set AttributeValue = AttributeName, AttributeName = AttributeValue`

Answer (score 6):

All the previous techniques are slow for big tables they move data instead of renaming columns, this is a simple solution:

```
ALTER TABLE "amplitude"
RENAME COLUMN "start_hour_displayed" TO "temp";

ALTER TABLE "amplitude"
RENAME COLUMN "start_hour" TO "start_hour_displayed";

ALTER TABLE "amplitude"
RENAME COLUMN "temp" TO "start_hour";
```

If you have views of functions linked you have to backup them before and restore them after.

Answer (score 3):

This is really good example

```
SELECT * from employees;
Go

DECLARE @temp as varchar(20)
update employees
set    @temp = fname,
       fname = lname,
       lname = @temp
WHERE  deptno = 10;
GO

SELECT * from employees;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you explain the behavior? Does the database engine first assign `fname` to `@temp`, then assing `lname` to `fname`, then `@temp` to `lname`? If this is the case, how do you explain `set a=b, b=a`?

Comment: Why would you do this? You don't need a swap variable, check Oded's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @myTable Table (id int, first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50));

Select * from Student

Insert Into @myTable (id, first_name, last_name) Select id, last_name, first_name from Student

    MERGE
    INTO    Student std
    USING @myTable tmp
    ON std.id = tmp.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET std.first_name = tmp.first_name,
    std.last_name = tmp.last_name;

Select * from Student
```

**Output**

[image: Query Result Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just swap both columns in a single update:

```
Update registration
Set AttributeName = AttributeValue ,
    AttributeValue = AttributeName where id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE employee
SET AttributeValue = AttributeName, 
    AttributeName = AttributeValue its not correct better to create one temp column and try the code
UPDATE employee
SET temp= AttributeName
then again 
UPDATE employee
SET AttributeName = AttributeValuee
again

UPDATE employee
SET AttributeValuee= temp