# MySQL - Swap values of two columns in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to correct some data in a table which stores two years:

```
id | start_year | end_year
---|------------|---------
1  |    2001    |   2003
2  |    2008    |   2005
3  |    2004    |   2010
4  |    2012    |   NULL
5  |    2003    |   2004
```

Like in row 2 the years are the wrong way round. How can I swap the values of those columns, on rows where `start_year > end_year`?

**Note:** row 4 should not be swapped, where `end_year` is NULL. That should remain the same.

Comment: Check this : [Swap Tables Columns values - SQL - arpit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198587/how-do-i-swap-column-values-in-sql-server-2008/44300052#44300052)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

Thus you cannot use a simple `UPDATE` command.  Instead, you can perform a self-join:

```
UPDATE myTable old
  JOIN myTable new USING (id)
SET    new.start_year = old.end_year,
       new.end_year = old.start_year
WHERE  old.start_year > old.end_year
```

Comment: Nice idea using a `JOIN`.

Comment: NOTE: This works only when the table has unique ID's (as in the example) otherwise there is no way to self-join the table

Comment: @EfrainPlaza: if you have tables without primary keys, you’ve got bigger problems than this.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of math magic can help:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET start_year = start_year - end_year,
    end_year   = end_year + start_year,
    start_year = end_year - start_year
WHERE start_year > end_year
  AND end_year IS NOT NULL
```

#### Remark

I cannot tell how reliable is this method of updating. In order to have the desired effect, the expressions must be computed and the assignments must be done in the order presented in the query. If MySQL decides to compute or assign them in a different order then the query will produce a mess in the table.

An excerpt from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

It is not very clear from the fragment above if the assignments are evaluated from left to right or not. It says "generally" but it doesn't explain what are the exceptions.

I tested the query on MySQL 5.5.24 using the small sample data provided in the question and it worked as expected.

#### Advice

Backup your table before running this query. You have been warned!

Comment: `start_year > end_year` entails `end_year IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @eggyal you are right. I prefer to make it explicit because it is specified in the question. It doesn't affect the speed or the outcome.